# Airbrake and mountable engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines, airbrake

My rails application has a mountable engine mounted on to it.  I'm using the airbrake gem on both my rails application and the mountable engine. But when I use  airbrake.notify on my mountable gem, it uses the airbrake from the rails application. How can I seperate the airbrake notifications of my rails application and the mountable engine(by use their own corresponding api_keys)?